# Faster Than Pushing To Heroku with Flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have been developing by pushing to Heroku - this is a little time consuming.

What is a faster approach to develop - using Flask?

Comment: Develop locally on your machine

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Flask/Web App Development - how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to develop on your own machine is to run it locally:

```
$ cd directory/containing/your/project
your/project$ python your_flask_app.py
* Running on 127.0.0.1:5000
```

Make sure that your `app.run` call has the keyword argument `debug` set to `True` so you get automatic reloading when you edit your application.  (e. g. `app.run(debug=True)`).

You can now visit localhost:5000 in your browser and edit the files on disk and see immediate changes (and errors).

If you don't already have Flask installed on your local machine this may fail with an `ImportError`.  In which case, simply ensure that you have virtualenv and pip installed on your machine and then do the following:

```
# Linux / Mac
your/project$ virtualenv --distribute venv
your/project$ source venv/bin/activate  # Alternately, you can use the . command
(venv) your/project$ pip install -r requirements.txt
(venv) your/project$ python your_flask_app.py

# Windows
your/project> virtualenv --distribute venv
your/project> venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) your/project> pip install -r requirements.txt
(venv) your/project> python your_flask_app.py
```

Comment: I get a KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL' error from the following line:

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

Comment: I thought DATABASE_URL was set by Heroku when I initialized Heroku, if I change this something else - like what? I am not sure - will my web app still work.

Comment: I followed these instructions from Heroku's docs - if I change this will the app break?


$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL
Promoting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL to DATABASE_URL... done

Comment: @RohitRayudu - You'll want to change that to `os.environ.get("DATABASE_URI", "/path/to/fallback/db.sqlite")` or something similar (since when you develop on your local machine you most likely don't have a database running).

Comment: Is it possible to run Postgres locally or is SQLite the only option - will a Postgres based app (or at least I can guarantee it works with Postgres) still work if I use SQLite locally?

Comment: @RohitRayudu - it is most certainly possible - it should be available for installation via your OS's packaging system (`apt-get`, `yum`, etc.)  If it is not, it is available for download from http://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: I have it installed via http://postgresapp.com/  But I am not able to create databases I get the following error - createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  - this occurs even though Postgres is running

Comment: I also wanted to add that I am searching for the answer on Google - I just haven't yet got the solution - so it's not that I am 100% relying on SO - just wanted to clarify that. :P

Comment: "/path/to/fallback/db.sqlite" - What is the postgres version of this

Comment: @RohitRayudu - Glad to hear it - as for the db path I was assuming that you could fall back to SQLite for development - if you need Posgres then you can ignore that :-)  As for what port to connect to Postgres on when running Posgresapp, you'll want to look in the app's help menu for that :-)

Comment: Thank you very much - I finally got it to work - on my 8th attempt at installing it lol. Thanks once again - it's so much quicker to develop locally than my previous method of pushing to Heroku all the time.